# static resources and spring mvc

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, controller

I know there are many asked questions regarding this issue, but mine is different, I could not find any solution based on previous questions. I am using spring MVC and everything worked fine until i found out that my browser is not rendering the images. Then I tried to give my browser the full url to my images and it returned 404. I tried with 
`<mvc:default-servlet-handler/>
 <mvc:resources mapping="/images/**" location="/images/"/>`

This did not get my images to display, but it also somehow messes up my controller, it is not handling the url mappings. I will show you most of my code.

Here is my **web.xml**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="3.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd">


<servlet>
    <servlet-name>spring-brains</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    <multipart-config/>
</servlet> 
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>spring-brains</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>   
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>
        index.jsp
    </welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list> 
<filter>
    <filter-name>characterEncodingFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter</filter-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>encoding</param-name>
        <param-value>UTF-8</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>forceEncoding</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </init-param>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>characterEncodingFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>

<filter>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>
        /WEB-INF/spring-brains-servlet.xml
    </param-value>
</context-param>
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>
<jsp-config>
    <jsp-property-group>
        <url-pattern>*.jsp</url-pattern>
        <page-encoding>UTF-8</page-encoding>
    </jsp-property-group>
</jsp-config>
```

Here is my **spring-brains-servlet.xml**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

```
<context:component-scan base-package="bobi.spring.spring.brains"/>

<bean id="viewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.UrlBasedViewResolver">
    <property name="viewClass" value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView"></property>
    <property name="prefix" value="/"></property>
    <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"></property>
</bean>

<mvc:default-servlet-handler/>
<mvc:resources mapping="/images/**" location="/images/"/>

<security:debug/>

<security:http pattern="/admin/login.jsp" security="none"/>
<security:http auto-config="true">
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/admin/**" access="ROLE_USER" />
    <security:form-login login-page="/admin/login.jsp" default-target-url="/admin/admin.jsp" always-use-default-target="true"/>             
    <security:logout logout-success-url="/admin" />
</security:http>

<bean class="service.DummyUserService" id="user-service-bobi"/>

<security:authentication-manager>
    <security:authentication-provider user-service-ref="user-service-bobi">
    </security:authentication-provider>
</security:authentication-manager>
```

and here is my **AdminController**:

```
/*


* To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package bobi.spring.spring.brains;

import domains.User;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.HashMap;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.MultipartConfig;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.http.Part;
import org.apache.commons.fileupload.FileUploadException;
import org.apache.commons.fileupload.servlet.ServletFileUpload;
import org.apache.commons.logging.Log;
import org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.CookieValue;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;
import service.Authentication;
import service.ProductManager;
import service.Service;

/**
 *
 * @author BOBBOO
 */
@MultipartConfig
@Controller
@RequestMapping(value = "/admin")
public class AdminController {

protected final Log logger = LogFactory.getLog(getClass());

@RequestMapping(value = "/{adminview}")
public ModelAndView getAdminView(@PathVariable("adminview") String view) {

    switch (view) {
        case "login": {
            return new ModelAndView("admin/login");
        }
        case "admin": {
            return new ModelAndView("admin/admin");
        }
        case "newcategory": {
            return new ModelAndView("admin/newcategory");
        }
        case "newproduct": {
            return new ModelAndView("admin/newproduct", "categories", Service.getCategories());
        }
        case "newuser": {
            return new ModelAndView("admin/newuser");
        }
        case "products": {

            return new ModelAndView("admin/products", "products", Service.getProducts());
        }
        default:
            return new ModelAndView("admin/login");
    }
}

@RequestMapping("/form")
public void formHandler(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException, FileUploadException {

    String formId = request.getParameter("formId");
    request.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
    if (formId != null && formId.equals("newcat")) {

        service.Admin.saveCategory((HashMap) ServletUtils.prepareRequestArguments(request));
        response.sendRedirect("admin/newcategory");
    } else if (formId != null && formId.equals("login")) {
        Authentication auth = new Authentication();
        User user = service.Service.getUser(request.getParameter("username"));

    } else if (formId != null && formId.equals("newuser")) {
        Authentication auth = new Authentication();
        boolean success = auth.CheckUserName(request.getParameter("username"));

        if (success) {
            service.Admin.saveUser((HashMap) ServletUtils.prepareRequestArguments(request));

            response.sendRedirect("admin/newuser");
        } else {
            response.sendRedirect("admin/login");
        }
    } 

}

@RequestMapping(value = "/upload")
public void productAdd(HttpServletRequest request,HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException, ServletException {
    if (ServletFileUpload.isMultipartContent(request)) {

        request.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
        Part part = request.getPart("picture");
        String path = service.Constants.LINUX_ABS_PROJECT_PATH + System.getProperty("file.separator") + "images";
        Service serv = new Service();
        String kategorija = request.getParameter("category");
        System.out.println(kategorija);
        try {
            serv.SaveFile(path, part);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        ServletUtils util = new ServletUtils();
        try {
            service.Admin.saveProduct((HashMap) util.prepareRequestMultiPartArguments(request));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            logger.info("Error while saving product @ AdminController, line 92!!");
        }

        response.sendRedirect(request.getContextPath() + "/admin/admin.jsp");

    }
}

@RequestMapping(value="/edit/{object}/{objectId}")
public ModelAndView editTable(@PathVariable("object") String editItemType, 
                               @PathVariable("objectId") String itemId){
switch(editItemType){
    case "product":{
        return new ModelAndView("admin/editproduct", "product", Service.getProduct(Integer.parseInt(itemId)));
    }
    case "category":{
    return new ModelAndView("admin/editcategory", "category", Service.getProduct(Integer.parseInt(itemId)));
    }
    case "user":{
    return new ModelAndView("admin/edituser", "user", Service.getProduct(Integer.parseInt(itemId)));
    }
}
return new ModelAndView("admin/admin");
}

@RequestMapping(value="/formedit")
public void editForm(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException, FileUploadException {

    String formId = request.getParameter("formId");
    request.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
    if (formId != null && formId.equals("newcat")) {

        service.Admin.saveCategory((HashMap) ServletUtils.prepareRequestArguments(request));
        response.sendRedirect("admin/newcategory");
    } else if (formId != null && formId.equals("login")) {
        Authentication auth = new Authentication();
        User user = service.Service.getUser(request.getParameter("username"));

    } else if (formId != null && formId.equals("newuser")) {
        Authentication auth = new Authentication();
        boolean success = auth.CheckUserName(request.getParameter("username"));

        if (success) {
            service.Admin.saveUser((HashMap) ServletUtils.prepareRequestArguments(request));

            response.sendRedirect("admin/newuser");
        } else {
            response.sendRedirect("admin/login");
        }
    } 

}
```

}

So basically I have two questions:
1. How to get my app to display static image content?
2. Why and how is this -->

```
<mvc:default-servlet-handler/>
 <mvc:resources mapping="/images/**" location="/images/"/>
```

messing up my controller, or what I say stopping it from handling the mappings it is supposed to handle.

Thank you in advance I have been struggling with this for days

Comment: First, don't have both your `DispatcherServlet` and `ContextLoaderListener` load the same context file.

Comment: Tomcat is asking for context listener and i don't see how am i loading the same with the DispatcherServlet

Comment: Notice your `<context-param>` for `/WEB-INF/spring-brains-servlet.xml`. Additionally, your `DispatcherServlet` is named `spring-brains`. By default, Spring looks for a context file named `<your-servlet-name>-servlet.xml` and loads it with the `DispatcherServlet`. In this, that's the same file as the `ContextLoaderListener`.

Comment: Okay, I answered 2. to myself, I was missing `<mvc:annotation-driven/>`. So my controller now works, but I still can not see my images, I don't see them whenever `<img src""/>` is supposed to show nor when I give my browser the full URL. I keep getting HTTP-404. Can anyone help me solve the other half, that is show the static content.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis when i comment the <context-param> partin my servlet.xml i get the following error:java.io.FileNotFoundException: Could not open ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml]

Comment: I don't know how but it is working now, if someone can close this question. The only thing i changed since asking the question was adding <mvc:annotation-driven/>

Answer (score -2):

You haven't include the jsp or view in your question.  Use the JSTL  tag to generate absolute paths from the root of the web-app:

```
<img src="<c:url value='/images/yourimage.jpg'/>">
```